# At the airport in-person check-in time when the flight is delayed

Tags: delays

If a flight is delayed, and they announce in advance the delay, is the check-in time also delayed?

Say, at 13h, the flight, that was scheduled for 16h, has an estimated departure for 16h30. If in-person at the airport check-in time was 15h20, is check-in time 15h50 now?

Edit:

Somehow this [If I know a flight is delayed can I turn up late for check-in at the airport?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/45289/if-i-know-a-flight-is-delayed-can-i-turn-up-late-for-check-in-at-the-airport?rq=1) answers my question.

Answer (score 1):

No.
That is clearly written on each airlines web sites. You are always required to appear according at the original scheduled times.

The main reason is that sometimes the delay disappears or reduces, and they want you to be present for boarding.

Comment: The point of announcing a delay is that people do not waste time. You still end up wasting time before the flight. :( The people waiting for you at the arrival won't waste theirs, which is OK, but only half as good.

Comment: @PierreB: You seem very sure about what "the" point of announcing a delay is. What makes you so convinced that it can't be such that passengers can start making arrangements for possibly arriving later than expected at their destination?

Comment: @HenningMakholm: yes, I imply that half the advantage is at the departure, the other half is at the arrival side. But if they know that the departure is 2h delayed, it sucks that they do not delay the checkin.

Comment: But it sucks even more if the 2 hours is reduced to 1 hour, but then the flight can't take off because some of the passengers are not there.